# Set cookie version of incoming httpServletRequest

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cookies, httpcookie

I have a client that is sending to me a version 1 cookie with a comma delimite value. This should be ok in version 1 of cookies but not allowed in version 0.

So this it the cookie

```
test.cookie=1,1
```

Now when I read Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies[] I am returned 2 cookies like this:

```
test.cookie=1
1=
```

So it is seeing the value of the cookie as a delimiter for the next cookie, which you would expect in version 0 of cookies. 
So the question is can I set the cookie version of the incoming HttpServletRequest before reading the cookies from it.

I know that there is a Cookie.setVersion(int) method but that is no use to me as I am not setting the cookie the container is. *(which might be a clue actually to set the cookie version in the container which I will go and look at now)*

**Edit**
The way I have worked around this is to just read the headers and then read the value of the Cookie header which comes as a semi-colon delimited list and then parse each cookie name value pair myself thus the comma in the value of the cookie is then preserved correctly and I get just the one cookie.  Be nice to know if there is a way of doing this with HttpServleRequest.getCookies() though.

Comment: who is setting the cookie? Is there a version field in the cookie like `version=0` or `version=1`?

Comment: @amicngh the requirement is to read a cookie that has a comma in the value as one cookie not two when using request.getCookies();

Comment: @TobiasN.Sasse the setting of the cookie is from the client which I have no control over

Comment: Which kind of client is that?

Comment: @TobiasN.Sasse one sending an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RFC2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965) and [RFC2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) the `,` character needs to be in quotes when used in value fields, thus `","`. That would help you to imply whether the comma is meant to separate two cookies or has a meaning in the value. In my understanding of [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) the `,` is not allowed at all.

Comment: so basically you are saying that a comma in a cookie value is invalid cookie notation unless the comma is surrounded by quotes. Thank you for the info.  The client cannot be changed and is beyond my control so I will have to go with my work around but thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding of the situation. From that I'd assume that the client is buggy. But I could also be mistaken in interpreting the RFCs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any control over the cookies from the client, then you are left with only option. 
Read the cookies as two part and combine them yourself into a single cookie and then make use of it.
Use something like the following:

```
new_cookie.setValue(cookies[0].getValue()+cookies[1].getValue());
```

Make the further manipulations with `new_cookie`

Comment: The problem with that is that it is incorrect from the start HttpServletRequest.getCookies() gives me an array of 2 cookies not one. It could be valid in one request but not for the next if the value has a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding the value in cookie solved this for me.